# How to make textbox ReadOnly from Caliburn.Micro ViewModel?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I started programming app on WP 7.1 with Caliburn.Micro. My starting view is a logging window with login and pass textboxes and button with log in action. Now I want to show progress bar on the top as indeterminate and make textboxes as readOnly. I have been searching in the web and found only not satisfacting me solutions. I am thinking about solutions like this:

1. Change default binder to bind properties by convention like "ControlNameIsReadOnly" "ControlNameIsEnabled"
2. Make screen as dialog box with only progress bar shown

Anybody has resolved this? None of those solutions are satisfacting me.

Comment: Did you find a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways - depends if you want to do it convention based and per-control

Without conventions you could use a busy property e.g.

```
class SomeViewModel : Screen // or whatever
{
    public bool IsBusy 
    {
        get { // getter code 
        } 
        set { // setter code, calling notifypropertychanged 
        }

}
```

Then in your control

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox>Hello World</TextBox>
        <Border Background="#AAFFFFFF"> <!-- Semitransparent overlay -->
            <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="true" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Your converter may look like this:

```
class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public void Convert(object value, blah blah blah...)
    {
        if(value is bool)
        {
            if((bool)value) return Visibility.Visible;

            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This way you can overlay the progressbar when things are happening on your control so the user cannot interact.

You may have to tweak for best fit as I've not tested any of that :P

You can even bind `IsReadOnly` on the textboxes to the `IsBusy` property. This is of course assuming you don't mind doing it the non-conventional method and that it all works on Windows Phone 7 :)